# Julia conditions on an undefined variable

Tags: julia

What is the shortest and the most clean way to perform such an control if x is NOT defined currently?

~isdefined(x) || x<0

Comment: your question isnt that clear, but from what I gather from your question, you're looking for a wrapper that checks if a variable exists or if its a negative number

Comment: It would seem more idiomatic to define x as Nullable{T}() and initialized to null, instead of piggybacking on the dynamic name space. This would promote better performance and better code.

Comment: Use `!` for boolean not. `~` is for bitwise not.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think isdefined function works with uninitialized variables only. For all other cases it gives error. It creates ambiguity here.  I'm sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you looking for:

```
if !isdefined(:x) || x < 0
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If x is not defined x<0 does not produce an error because this checking is not performed. I did not expect this behavior from Julia. For example Matlab would produce an error.

Comment: Matlab too should produce the error if you use | instead of || (unless you using a very old Matlab version). I think this is common to several programming languages. The idea is that if the first condition is false, why waste time computing the second (and risk an error)? They call it shortcircuiting I think.

Comment: I don't know how to edit my previous comment. I meant first condition true (so !isdefined false).

Comment: isdefined false

Comment: No problem I understand.